# How do you calculate IRR in R (without using any packages)?

Tags: r, finance

I am trying to calculate IRR from by using input from a existing dataframe. I have used Newton-Raphson method iteration for calculation. However, I am not able to get an output.Further, the warning says:
In cashflows/(1 + rate)^(0:length(cashflows) - 1) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I would be greatful if someone can help me.

```
IRR <- function(cashflows) {
  rate <- 0.1
  max_iterations <- 1000
  tolerance <- 0.0001
  npv <- sum(cashflows / (1 + rate)^(0:length(cashflows)-1))
  
  for (i in 1:max_iterations) {
    npv_derivative <- sum(-1 * cashflows * (0:length(cashflows)-1) / (1 + rate)^(1:length(cashflows)))
    npv_second_derivative <- sum(cashflows * (0:length(cashflows)-1) * (1:length(cashflows)) / (1 + rate)^(2:length(cashflows)))
    rate <- rate - npv / npv_derivative
    if (abs(npv) < tolerance) {
      return(rate)
    }
    if (npv_second_derivative < 0) {
      return(NA)
    }
    npv <- sum(cashflows / (1 + rate)^(0:length(cashflows)-1))
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what IRR is, let alone how to calculate it.  (Not everyone knows what you think might be obvious.)  But I suspect you might need `0:(length(cashflows)-1)` throughout.  Also, you don't update `npv` within your loop, yet you use `npv` as your stopping condition.  That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function `IRR` that solves the problem. The input is different, the function's arguments are

1. `cashflows` are the cashflows;
2. `initial` is the total initial capital costs.

In the example below the cashflows vector and the initial capital are taken from the Excel example in [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irr.asp). Their result is 56.72%, the same as the one computed by `IRR`.

```r
IRR <- function(cashflows, initial) {
  f <- function(x, C, C0) sum(C/(1 + x)^seq_along(C)) - C0
  uniroot(f, c(0, 100), C = cashflows, C0 = initial)$root
}

x <- seq(100000, 300000, 50000)  
x0 <- 250000
IRR(x, x0)
#> [1] 0.5672364
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>